# C# Tuple of List replace/erase previous data

Tags: c#, list, tuples

Thank you for all your messages that really helped me, I finally decide to post here. I just discovered Tuples which allow me to create List of List with other element.
Here is my simplified code :

```
public class Category { //Classe "Category" comprenant le nom de la category et sa proportion de CIR
        public string category_name {get; set;}
        public string proportion {get; set;}
    }
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    var Projects = new List<Tuple<string, List<Category>>>();
    while(...)
        { [...]
            var List_Categories = new List<Category>()
            while(...)
            { [...]
            List_Categories.Add(category_example);
            }
        Projects.Add(Tuple.Create(nom_projet, List_Categories);
        }
    }
```

My "Category" class is just 2 strings. A "project" is a List AND a string (project_name) hence my using of Tuple for this. 
1st question : I would have create a class for "project" but I could not find how to put a Tuple as a parameter of a class ? (he do not recognize the "var" type as a parameter)
Then, 2nd question : I have an issue : when the program going on, inside "Projects" (which is a List of "project"), the "project_name" is writting well but the "Category" data is each time replaced by the new one for EVERY index of the list. I do not know how such a thing is possible ...

Thank you very much, I hope you can understand my problem, I am very sorry about my English but it is not my native language. I will reformulate if it's not understandable.

Comment: "I just discovered Tuples which allow me to create List of List with other element." Boy will you be excited, when you discover `Dictionary<string, List<Category>>`... ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem like you want a tuple as a property in your project class, it seems like what you want is this:

```
public class Project
{
    public string project_name {get; set;}
    public List<Category> categories {get; set;}
}
```

And as Corak mentioned, I think a Dictionary might help with your other issue.

By the way, the reason you can't use `var` as the type of a property is that it isn't a type -- it's just a shorthand way of declaring a variable without explicitly specifying the type of that variable (the compiler figures it out), but it [only works on local variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx). You can't use it for a property because the compiler would have no way to figure out what the type of that property is supposed to be. The type of a [tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) is `Tuple<T1, T2,...>` -- for example, your tuples here are `Tuple<string, List<Category>>`, and you could certainly have a class property of that type if you wanted.

Comment: I already tried Dictionnary but it did not help. But your solution with the class "Project" works perfectly well ! Thank you very much, as I was not be able to use "var", I did not know how to create a class with a List as a parameter.
Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a dictionary instead

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var Projects = new Dictionary<string, List<Category>>();
    while(...)
    { [...]
        var List_Categories = new List<Category>()
        while(...)
        { [...]
            List_Categories.Add(category_example);
        }
        Projects.Add(nom_projet, List_Categories);
    }
}
```

By creating a tuple on every single loop, you are overwriting previous work.  With a dictionary you can simply add to your collection inside of your loops